# Mining Linkedin data using Linkedin api

Tags: api, linkedin-api, mining

I am new to linkedin api , and am not sure if what i plan to do is a possibility or not. What I want to do is , gather data of people working at , say Google. So I put in a search query "google" and whatever employees i find , i want their school attended, highest degree and position in company. 
I also want to find , for a given employee, how many connections he has who belong to the same company / school.

Based on the data i collect i plan do some clustering to find groups and connectedness.

Is it possible using the api they have provided ? Or do i need some VIP membership ? I am currently looking at python api , but others are also fine .